# Left join with same table making query too slow -- MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, query-performance

We have a table **server_user_disk_usage** which tracks the disk usage of users from different servers. 
Query is to find sum of last disk usage of each user from different servers

```
SELECT
m1.user_name,
sum(m1.disk_usage) as disk_usage
FROM server_user_disk_usage m1 
LEFT JOIN server_details s on s.id = m1.server_id
LEFT JOIN server_user_disk_usage m2
ON (m1.server_id = m2.server_id  and m1.user_name = m2.user_name AND 
m1.epoch < m2.epoch)
WHERE m2.epoch IS NULL 
GROUP BY m1.user_name
order by cast(sum(m1.disk_usage) as unsigned) desc;
```

Response is correct but its too slow when moved to production because of huge data. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Specify server version. 5+ or 8+?

Comment: `cast(sum(m1.disk_usage) as unsigned)` - does disk_usage can be negative??

Comment: version is 5+ . disk_usage  will not be negative and cast(sum(m1.disk_usage) as unsigned) doesn't have any impact. Its totally because of left join, when we remove left join query will be fast.

Comment: Do you have an index on `(server_id, user_name, epoch`? It would be best if you provided the output of `CREATE TABLE name;` for all involved tables and the execution plan (output of `EXPLAIN SELECT ...your_query...;`)

Comment: i added index on (server_id, user_name, epoch) and now query is fast.Thanks @ypercubeᵀᴹ

Comment: Smells like a "groupwise-max" problem.  Search for that.  There are a lot of inefficient ways, and you picked one of the worst.

Comment: why is `LEFT JOIN server_details` in this query? You don't use the results anywhere or use if for filtering.

Comment: @danblack I am using the same query in another procedure where i need to get last  record based on server where i need to show server name, Here i forgot remove that line. Thanks for notifying.

Comment: @RickJames Thanks for that input ill check on that , Any ways my problem is solved after adding index itself. But still ill check on this and hope ill get the best solution.